# Any good analytical approximation for the inverse factorial moment of Poisson random variable?

Tags: probability, factorial, gamma-function, poisson-distribution

I have the following question:

Consider a random variable $M \sim \mathrm{Poisson} (\lambda)$. I would like to evaluate the following expectation:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left[ 1 / \Gamma (M + a) \right]
\end{align*}
where $a$ is a fixed positive integer and $\Gamma (\cdot)$ is just the gamma function.

I would like to obtain an analytical expression for the above quantity. If some further restriction helps, we can consider the case where both $a$ and $\lambda$ are large.